# Converting XML node to upper case in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert an attribute value to upper case and use the below piece of xslt to transform it. But, the words are not converted fully.

```
<xsl:param
    name="lang_lower"
    select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:param
    name="lang_upper"
    select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:template match="//*[@attributename]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="L">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@attributename, $lang_lower, $lang_upper)" />
  </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='attributename']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But, sometimes, the values in the attribute ('attributename') is not getting converted.

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete XML sample and a minimal but complete XSLT sample allowing us to reproduce the problem, together with information about the used XSLT processor, the result you get and the result you want.

Comment: When I transform using this template, then some of the words are converted and the rest are just left out. E.g in 'de', the output is converted as 'dE' and not as 'DE' etc.

Comment: At the same time, the transform for changing the case happens at the end of the template. But, there is another xslt template which for the parent of 'attributename'. In this case, is there any problem with the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any information to allow us to reproduce the problem, the only oddity I see is that instead of matching on the attribute you want to transform you match on its parent element. So I would change the code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:param
    name="lang_lower"
    select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:param
    name="lang_upper"
    select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@attributename">
    <xsl:attribute name="L">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $lang_lower, $lang_upper)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which then should do fine, see http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWo where the input

```
<root>
    <foo attributename="de" bar="baz"/>
</root>
```

is transformed to the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root>
    <foo L="DE" bar="baz"/>
</root>
```

If you still have problems then provide minimal but complete samples allowing others to reproduce the problem.